# How to store text of textview using checkbox in arraylist

Tags: android, checkbox

I am using listview and I am displaying a `json` response to my `listview`, I am displaying the `price` from `json` in my `listview`,so when I check `checkbox`, the price selected list item should be stored in array list, this is my code:

```
public class CustomAdapterPooja extends BaseAdapter {

        private  LayoutInflater inflater=null;
         Context context;
        private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> listData;
        private static final String TAG_POOJA_NAME="pooja_name";
        private static final String TAG_POOJA_AMOUNT="amount";
        private static final String TAG_POOJA_DAYS="worship";
        Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        public CustomAdapterPooja(FragmentActivity mainActivity, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> listData) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

            context = mainActivity;
            this.listData=listData;
            inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return listData.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        public class Holder
        {
            TextView tv;
            TextView serviceprice;

            public CheckBox checks;
            public TextView dayss;
            public ImageView seledates;
            public TextView txtseledates;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final Holder holder=new Holder();
            String rup="\u20B9";
            View rowView;
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_poojaselection, null);
            holder.tv=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_poojaname);
            holder.serviceprice=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_poojaprice);
            holder.dayss=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_poojadays);
            holder.seledates=(ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_selectdates);
            holder.txtseledates=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.selecteddatess);


            holder.checks=(CheckBox)rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_poojacheck);

            holder.checks.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    System.out.println("hello"+listData.get(position).get(TAG_POOJA_AMOUNT));
                }
            });

            holder.seledates.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {



                    datePickerDialog.show();


                }
            });
            holder.tv.setText(listData.get(position).get(TAG_POOJA_NAME));
            holder.dayss.setText(listData.get(position).get(TAG_POOJA_DAYS));
            holder.serviceprice.setText(rup + listData.get(position).get(TAG_POOJA_AMOUNT));

            datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    sYear = year;
                    sMonth = monthOfYear;
                    sDate = dayOfMonth;
                    holder.txtseledates.setText(new StringBuilder()
                            // Month is 0 based, just add 1
                            .append(sYear).append("-").append(sMonth + 1).append("-").append(sDate));
                /*selecdts=textcal.getText().toString();
                System.out.println("Selected dtes"+selecdts);*/
                }
            }, newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
            return rowView;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Which TextView value want to store?

Comment: listData.get(position).get(TAG_POOJA_AMOUNT)..this one is for price..that i want to store as per checkbox selection

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK how can do that

Comment: @Jolly where have you defined the arraylist for storage?

Comment: i have no idea where to add that

Answer (score 0):

You can get checked item in ListView as below -

```
SparseBooleanArray checked = listData.getCheckedItemPositions();

for (int i = 0; i < YourListView.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
    if (checked.get(i)) {
        // Store `listData.get(position).get(TAG_POOJA_AMOUNT));` in an ArrayList
    }
}
```

Comment: where can i add this??

Comment: In YourActivity.class

Comment: Nope. You need to add it in Activity.